# How often is month's top question ranking updated?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, hot-questions

How often is the question list shown at "month" (hot) tab https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month updated?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say... every month? :)

Comment: Another possibility is that it's updated on a "rolling" basis, i.e shows the "hottest" things from the past 30 days ?